# How browsec works?

Tags: vpn, proxy

I am trying to find out how browsec works. In my college, youtube is banned. When I type youtube.com in my url, the packets carrying the url travels to the proxy server. The proxy server here blocks the packet.

```
system -----------> proxy server ------------> youtube
                       ||
             the packet is dropped here
```

Now I want to use browsec. So, again I try to connect youtube.com. When I type url the packet should again travel to the proxy server and should be dropped there.

```
system -----------> proxy server ----------> browsec ------------> youtube
                       ||
             the packet should be dropped here, but doesn't happen. Why?
```

So, what I think that packets are dropped at proxy server of my college in both cases. So, how does it work? Is there any type of encryption / decryption?

Comment: Do you know it is a proxy server? Or might it be some other solution blocking this traffic? If a proxy server, which one and how is it configured?

Comment: Looks like I couldn't state my question properly. What I want to know is how browsec control the packets? How does it work. The browsec is working fine.

Comment: It simply encrypts the traffic to bypass the proxy/firewall and takes you to a browsec proxy location. Makes you lot like you are originating out of a different country. Sounds like you're college doesn't use an intelligent firewall product with signatures looking for browsec to block based on signatures. Somewhat surprised that a college blocks youtube in today's world. May be a bandwidth issue.

Comment: So, basically there is no involvement of the proxy-server of my college?  Yeah, youtube is banned for students only, but who cares.

Comment: Since we don't help people circumvent network policies here, I think this question is off-topic.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professional managed networks. This question seems to be more related to applications and how they functions rather than a question about networks, even if they do use a network. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

It works because you aren't asking to *youtube* from the proxy; you're requesting some other site, that then sends you to youtube. (aka a "VPN", or "tunnel")